# "There is to do something" natural?

Tags: phrase-meaning, lyrics

In the song "**Everyday**" by Phil Collins there's a lyric:

- Every way there is to cry, ourselves to sleep we will.

Is the phrase "**there Is to do something**" valid and natural English?

I'm striving hard to understand this whole part actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe "there is to do something" is used **only** in the formulation, "any/every way there is to do something, he/she/they will".  It's not a *common* expression, but it is grammatically acceptable.  Another example would be "Any way there is to cheat on an exam, your students will find it."

However, the comma in the Phil Collins example is in the wrong place grammatically. When viewed in the context of the rest of the lyrics, it's clearly being used to mark the end of the verse (in the poetic sense of the term), in the same way other lyrics might use a slash (/).

Comment: The way he sings there are two commas. One before "*ourselves to sleep*", the other one after.

Comment: Like I said, grammatically there should only be a comma after "sleep" (it's not required, but it makes it easier to understand the meaning when reading it). The first comma is being used to mark a musical beat, not for its usual purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rephrase this line as "There is every way to cry, and we will [cry ourselves to sleep](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cry+oneself+to+sleep)".

*There's something to do* sounds more grammatical than *there is to do something*--whether the latter is valid and natural English I very much doubt-- but it is a song after all to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

I read this line differently because the comma seems misplaced. The sense seems to be "We will cry ourselves to sleep in every way possible." Logically that is hard to parse because it makes no real difference whether we cry ourselves to sleep on the couch on our back or in our bed on our side. But songs do not have to be logical to evoke emotions. If my reading is correct, the comma is grammatically wrong. Of course, the comma was not sung.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in case it's causing any confusion, the punctuation should be "Every way there is to cry ourselves to sleep, we will."

You can't say "there is to do something" on its own and have it make sense, but what's happening is that the words "there is" are joined to the word "way" in a noun phrase. The rules for "way" get extended to the "way there is" noun phrase as a whole, so since one can say "a way to do something," one can also say "a way there is to do something." (One can also say  "a way of doing something" -- see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149291/is-there-a-difference-between-way-of-doing-something-and-way-to-do-something .)

Consider:

- Every way imaginable to climb the mountain, I tried.
- Every imaginable way to climb the mountain, I tried.

i.e.

- I tried every way imaginable to climb the mountain.
- I tried every imaginable way to climb the mountain.

In this case, "imaginable" is modifying "way", instead of "there is." (You couldn't say "every there is way to cry ourselves to sleep" but "every possible way to cry ourselves to sleep" is ok. The reason the analogy is imperfect is that "there is" is not an adjective, but the "way there is" *is* acting as a noun phrase.)

However, in the Collins case, the "we will" doesn't (on its own) really match up to the pre-comma part; it's actually referring to just the "cry ourselves to sleep" part. In other words, he actually meant "Using every way there is to cry ourselves to sleep, we will cry ourselves to sleep." It might be more correct (albeit less lyrical) for the lyrics to have been written as "Every way there is to cry ourselves to sleep, we will use."

Consider the saying "Where there's a will, there's a way." That saying, in a more expanded form, would be "Where there is a will to do something, there is a way to do something."